# Add commas after each element in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this huge input file

Sample:

```
[[127.53255528][127.35094646][127.41961045][127.68120798][128.06266054][128.50548745][128.97200957][129.44174   ][129.9054857 ][130.36031292][130.80617847][131.24415897][131.67550075]
```

I want to add commas after each element

Please tell me how to do it

Comment: What is your end goal? load this text file as a list? dataframe?

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Load input as a string, then replace brackets

```
str = "[[127.53255528][127.35094646][127.41961045][127.68120798][128.06266054][128.50548745][128.97200957][129.44174   ][129.9054857 ][130.36031292][130.80617847][131.24415897][131.67550075]]"

str = str.replace('][',",")
str = str.replace('[[',"")
str = str.replace(']]',"")



print(str)
```